# Cannot force Print support app for every printer

Tags: windows, winapi, printing, policy, regedit

In [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devapps/print-support-app-association), it shows `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\PSA\Association` path is used for overriding user's printer dialog for every(?) printer. But it also shows this photo:

[image]

What does this image imply? I use [this app](https://github.com/microsoft/print-oem-samples), by the way.